# New installation of Windows XP on new hard drive does not recognize 2 previously installed sata drives with Ubuntu

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows

Drives are recognized in hardware manager but are not recognized in MyComputer so can not be accessed from Windows. Disks are shown with a primary partition and a 7.5g logical drive'

Comment: Can you assing a drive letter to them on hardware manager or disc management on windows?

Answer (score 0):

Windows can't see hard drives that are formatted with Ubuntu usually.  If you want to share files between them you are going to need to either login to your Ubuntu and save them to the Windows drive or make an NTFS partition that is your share for both OSes.

If you can't login to your ubuntu then you probably need to repair grub.  http://www.howopensource.com/2012/05/reinstall-recover-grub-from-ubuntu-12-04-live-cd-usb/

Hope this helps.